# Cookies being posted across domain

Tags: cookies, web-application-firewall, azure-front-door

I recently switched on a WAF on our public facing website. This has caused a number of false positives and I believe legitimate users are occasionally getting blocked.

Many of these false positives are being caused by values in cookies which are triggering rules but upon inspection it looks like these cookies don't belong to us or our domain...

The most baffling one I've seen is

```
"matchVariableName": "CookieValue:handl_url",
"matchVariableValue": "https://xxxxxxx.com/competition-terms?utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&_hsenc=[removed--hash]"
```

A quick search on google for "handl_url" suggests that the cookie is used to store the URL that the cookie was created on, but the domain in the cookie is not our domain...

So my questions are...

1. what could cause a browser to post cookies across domains like this?
2. could this be a bugged browser or attack on the website?
3. does this happen commonly on public facing websites?

For reference, we use Google Tag Manager (gtm) on our site so their may be links to other sites embedded on our website but I'm pretty sure the domain in my example isn't one of them.

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: What domain are you using? I wonder if your seeing a similar problem I have where cookies set from other sites using the same domain name are attaching to requests to my site which share the same domain. Read the domain section here: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Directives).

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, very interesting... I read the link you added and then this one... https://datacadamia.com/web/http/cookie_domain I'm still not entirely sure how the domain option works but I can confirm my team doesn't manage all sub domains (some point at third parties). Maybe one of these sub domains is posting cookies back to our main domain but as were using www. I'm not sure if that would be valid...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the cookie in question contains a URL and might be related to tracking parameters, possibly from an email campaign using HubSpot ***(as indicated by the _hsenc parameter)***. The fact that the domain in the cookie doesn't match yours could be due to the way tracking cookies work.

Here are some possible explanations for this behavior:

```
Possible Causes:
    Third-Party Cookies: External resources (analytics, ads) can set cookies.
    Referer Leakage: Referring site's URL may be stored in a cookie.

Solutions:
    Whitelist Domains: Allow legitimate third-party domains.
    Refine WAF Rules: Fine-tune rules to prevent false positives.
    Adjust Cookie Handling: Be more lenient or exclude specific cookies.
    Check Browser Extensions: Ensure no unexpected extensions inject cookies.
    User Education: Guide users on configuring browsers/extensions.
    WAF Provider Support: Consult with WAF provider for insights and assistance.
```